# why custom generated pointcloud2 is displayed as line on rviz?

Tags: ros, point-cloud, rviz

I am new in ROS, We are developing LiDAR camera and I am trying to interface out LiDAR camera with ROS. I am using ROS 1 noetic on windows 10, I wrote a python script to convert the depth image generated from out camera to PointCloud2 format and then publish the generated PointCloud2 format.

When I try to display the PiontCloud2 on Rviz , the pointcloud is displayed as line on screen as here
[image]
or nothing is dispalyed at all

here is a single PointCloud2 sample

```
header: 
  seq: 8
  stamp: 
    secs: 1661780280
    nsecs: 110538482
  frame_id: "LiDAR1"
height: 80
width: 260
fields: 
  - 
    name: "x"
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 20800
  - 
    name: "y"
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 20800
  - 
    name: "z"
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 20800
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 12
row_step: 3120
data: [130, 115, 134, 191, 118, 171, 231, 190, 23, 217, 78, 64, 103 ....]
is_dense: True
---
```

I generate the Point Cloud by converting my depth image using camera parameters, applying the following command and then convert it to string

```
#cx shift of camera center from sensor center in x direction measured in pixels
   #cy shift of camera center from sensor center in y direction measured in pixels
   #fx=fy focal length in  meters
   #rows no of rows per frame
   #cols no of columns per frame

    c, r = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-cols/2,cols/2), np.arange(-rows/2,rows/2), sparse=True)
    z = np.float32(depth/1000)
    x = np.float32(z * (c - cx) * pixel_width / fx )
    y = np.float32(z * (r - cy) * pixel_higth / fy )
    ptcloud = np.dstack((x, y, z)).tostring()
```

my question is where's my mistake, is it in the PointCloud2 Format, or data or in Rviz configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing my code to the link sent by @Tully above, I could found the mistake.
Here's the corrected code

```
c, r = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-cols/2,cols/2), np.arange(-rows/2,rows/2), sparse=True)
z = np.float32(depth) #depth/1000 ==> float point cloud represent points in meters
x = np.float32(z * (c - cx) * pixel_width / fx )
y = np.float32(z * (r - cy) * pixel_higth / fy )
z = z.reshape(1,-1)
x = x.reshape(1,-1)
y = y.reshape(1,-1)
brightness = brightness.reshape(1,-1)
ptcloud = np.dstack([x, y, z, np.float32(brightness)])
return ptcloud.reshape(-1,4).tolist()
```

and changed msg.fields count to 1 instead of 20800

```
    msg.fields = [
        PointField('x', 0, PointField.FLOAT32, 1),
        PointField('y', 4, PointField.FLOAT32, 1), 
        PointField('z', 8, PointField.FLOAT32, 1), 
        PointField('intensity', 12, PointField.FLOAT32, 1) ]
```

and creaded the pointcloud2 using

```
pc2 = point_cloud2.create_cloud(msg.header, msg.fields, data)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad that you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly I suspect that it's an error in your population of the point cloud.

I'd recommend that you make a simple publisher that just publishes a known pattern that's easily debugged first to make sure that you understand the point cloud format correctly. rviz uses a bunch of these for tests such as here: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/noetic-devel/src/test/send_point_cloud_2.py

And then you afterwards leverage that knowledge to fill in the data from your sensor.

I don't think that there's any rviz settings that will significantly warp or reduce a dimension or two of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in your conversion. Why does the depth/height of the content affect the x/y position? Your code has:

```
c, r = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-cols/2,cols/2), np.arange(-rows/2,rows/2), sparse=True)
z = np.float32(depth/1000)
x = np.float32(z * (c - cx) * pixel_width / fx )
y = np.float32(z * (r - cy) * pixel_higth / fy )
```

but why are `x` and `y` dependent on `z` there? I would think you're looking for something like the [Matlab `surf` command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html), but [the example in the Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#bvgppvs-4) looks like:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

In this example, the x/y points are fixed and only the z-values vary. I would urge you to really consider what the x/y values are supposed to be and whether or not depth actually affects those values.

Comment: I have validated the conversion to pointcloud in pcd and pcl format, and I could display it correctly.
The conversion I am using is to convert from 2D depth information to pointcloud in pointCloud2 format.